# Javers audit a custom delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javers

What way Javers audit a custom 'delete'?
Using spring-boot integration,
for example:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(" delete from ExecutePayment exeP " +
                " where exeP.customer = :customer " +
                "   and exeP.status = 'EXECUTED' ")
        void deletePendingExecutionsFromCustomer(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

Comment: Maybe use Aspect ??

Comment: And for each resulting data of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JaVers doesn't support JPA query language. You need to wrap this method and call `javers.commitShallowDelete()` manually.